# Should I install a custom webapp in /opt or /srv?

Tags: software-installation, web, fhs

My understanding is that [custom/non-distro software should be installed in `/opt`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES). However in a Django deployment tutorial [[1](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2016/02/10/deploying-python-web-apps-with-nginx-and-uwsgi-emperor/)] I found a suggestion to install a Django webapp to `/srv` which is described as containing [site-specific data which is served by the system](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM).

Should non-distro webapps be installed in `/opt` or `/srv`?

Answer (score 1):

According to FHS `/srv` is for the site-specific data, not software packages (and is a just newer alternative to `/var` in this respect)

> /srv contains site-specific data which is served by this system

however if you are running a Django webapp with (say) Apache, your webapp can be classified as a *data* for it, so it should go to `/srv/` (just like you would have deployed it to `/var/www` on an older system).

And FHS does clearly hints on that:

> writable data and scripts (such as cgi scripts) can be reasonably placed

Comment: in this context does "site" mean "website"?

Comment: @d3vid - more like 'internet host', which can in turn serve a website (or multiple websites), mail service, NNTP site e.t.c.

So `/srv` will contain the webapps, mailboxes, news feeds e.t.c.